# Google Ads API- Need to fetch store_visit value

Tags: google-ads-api

As part of business ad campaigns across Google ads platform, we need to pull the value for store visits.
Current API endpoint being used in postman and the query:

https://googleads.googleapis.com/v14/customers/2332680615/googleAds:searchStream

"query":"SELECT campaign.id,campaign.name,campaign.status,metrics.impressions,metrics.clicks,metrics.cost_micros,segments.date FROM campaign where segments.date ='yyyy-mm-dd'"

I need to add store visit here, so that number looks like below (this screenshot from dashboard UI):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMbX4.png)

I did try below query too but not getting the desired numeric value:
"query":"SELECT conversion_action.app_id, conversion_action.category FROM conversion_action WHERE customer.id = 2332680615 AND conversion_action.category = 'STORE_VISIT'"

Can someone please help with this?